# how to get a character by character and store it in two dimensional array in java using scanner function

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a program which reads the input line and store it in a two dimensional character array.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        char[][] a = new char[4][5];

        Scanner inn = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                a[i][j] = inn.next().charAt(i + j);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                System.out.println(a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i get runtime error.Can anyone say how to resolve it.

Comment: What `runtime` error you are getting?

Comment: What is expected `input` and `output`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should say what the error is for any reasonable answers.

But looking at your code it could be because you are trying to get `inn.next()` multiple times in a loop.

Try this.

```
String value = inn.next();
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        a[i][j]=value.charAt(i*5+j);

    }
}
```

Comment: also I dont think charAt(i+j) is not what OP need.

Comment: You are right, I think its more like (i*5 + j). I will update the answer.

Comment: Yes it must be more accurate ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change the size of 2 Dimensional array as per your need. 
import java.util.*;

```
class StringToCharArray
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a String");
        char c[] = scan.next().toCharArray();
        int i,j,k=0,m;
        char data[][] = new char[10][10];
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                    data[i][j] = c[k];
                    k++;
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(data[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the whole String first and then you can get it char by char:

```
    String s = inn.next();
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=s.charAt(i+j);

        }
    }
```

But make sure that the string is long enough. If not you get an StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look, enter a character then hit the enter key.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        char[][] a = new char[4][5];

        Scanner inn = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++) {
                a[i][j] = inn.next().toCharArray()[0];

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++) {
                System.out.println(a[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }
```